# What should the [setting] tag be used for?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have a tag [setting](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/setting) with 7 questions so far:

- [one](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/509/17), [two](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/1758/17), [three](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/2203/17) asking about whether places in a story can be connected to real locations;
- [one](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/730/17) asking about when a particular story was set;
- [one](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/1811/17) asking about the realism of a feat described in a book;
- [one](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/1976/17) asking about ethnic diversity in a fictional universe;
- [one](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/2120/17) asking about the inspiration or significance behind a choice of location.

These all seem to be quite different types of question, and I'm not sure if all of them should have the [setting](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/setting) tag, or indeed what kind of question this tag is really meant for.

### **How should the [setting](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/setting) tag be used, if at all?**

I'm leaning towards thinking that this tag should be got rid of altogether. But if the consensus is that it's worth keeping for some particular class of questions, then let's get some clear usage guidance which we can turn into a tag wiki excerpt, and then add/remove this tag to/from some questions if necessary.

Comment: Please remove your opinion from the question and post on an answer. Otherwise it confuses people ("do I upvote because it's an interesting issue, or downvote because I disagree with your in-question answer?")

Comment: @DVK You mean the first sentence of the last paragraph? That's a very small part of the question to be worth voting on, and not even much of an opinion ("leaning towards" - I haven't made up my mind what to think). Anyway I don't much care if people downvote the question; votes on the answer(s) are more important.

Answer (score -2):

If we don't even have double digit uses of a tag yet, I don't think we know enough to make an informed decision about its use--and by the same token it's not a big enough problem to matter that we aren't making a decision yet.

Let the citizenry use the tag organically for a while longer and see what trends emerge.

Comment: Propose consistent usage of a single digit tag - get told there's not enough information yet to decide on one, so it's better to just keep on with the current inconsistency. Propose consistent usage of a double or triple digit tag - get told that retagging would disfigure the front page of the site too much, so it's better to just keep on with the current inconsistency.

Comment: @Randal'Thor [shrug] You know I disagree with the idea that tagging inertia should never be allowed to build because it's too inconvenient to divert it later. My suggestion and those are not intended to be compatible.

Comment: To be clear, I wasn't accusing *you* of expressing both of those views. It's just frustrating that every time I propose tidying up the tag system, there's always *some* reason to leave things messy and inconsistent.

Comment: @Randal'Thor A Stack's tag system is supposed to always be a little untidy; that's how we know it's alive. There are definitely times and reasons for tidying up, but a site as young as ours isn't going to have many of them yet.